# Joining two dataframes based on a timeframe condition, in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

I have a df:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2018-01-01"), A = c("5", NA), B = c("4", "0"))


       date    A B
 2020-01-01    5 4
 2018-01-01 <NA> 0
```

And a second df:

```
df2 <- data.frame(date = c("2020-05-16", "2018-09-23", "2017-02-02"), C = c("2", "3", "4"), D = c("9", "10", "11"))

       date C  D
 2020-05-16 2  9
 2018-09-23 3 10
 2017-02-02 4 11
```

I want to join the two dfs such that only dates that are in df2 which are **after df1's date and within 12 months** are joined to df1. (while keeping df1's date).

The result of this join should hopefully look like the following:

```
df_result <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2018-01-01"), A = c("5", NA), B = c("4", "0"), C = c("2", "3"), D = c("9", "10"))

       date    A B C  D
 2020-01-01    5 4 2  9
 2018-01-01 <NA> 0 3 10
```

Joining if the dates are equal is easy using inner_join. However, I am not quite sure how to do an inner join with a condition that is not simply x = y.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Convert the dates to Date class and then use the indicated left join.

```
library(sqldf)

df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2018-01-01"), 
  A = c("5", NA), B = c("4", "0"))
df2 <- data.frame(date = c("2020-05-16", "2018-09-23", "2017-02-02"), 
  C = c("2", "3", "4"), D = c("9", "10", "11"))

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date)
   
sqldf("select a.*, b.C, b.D
  from df1 a
  left join df2 b on b.date > a.date and b.date - a.date <= 365")
##         date    A B C  D
## 1 2020-01-01    5 4 2  9
## 2 2018-01-01 <NA> 0 3 10
```

In the sample data there is one match per row of df1 but if there could be several matches and we want only the least then

```
sqldf("select a.*, b.C, b.D, min(b.date - a.date) date_diff
  from df1 a
  left join df2 b on b.date > a.date and b.date - a.date <= 365
  group by a.rowid
  order by a.rowid")[-6]
```

### Added

Regarding the comment below this left joins `df1` and `df2` on the same conditions but for each `df2` row in the join keeps only the `df1` row that is nearest to it giving `mm`.  Then it left joins `df1` to `mm` to ensure that all rows of `df1` are represented.

```
library(sqldf)

# added third row to df1 as per comment
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2020-02-02"), 
  A = c(5, NA, 1), B = c(4, 0, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(date = c("2020-05-16", "2018-09-23", "2017-02-02"), 
  C = c(2, 3, 4), D = c(9, 10, 11))
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date)

mm <- sqldf("select a.*, b.C, b.D, min(b.date - a.date) date_diff
  from df1 a
  left join df2 b on b.date > a.date and b.date - a.date <= 365
  group by b.rowid")
sqldf("select a.*, b.C, b.D
  from df1 a
  left join mm b using(date)")
    date  A B  C  D
## 1 2020-01-01  5 4 NA NA
## 2 2018-01-01 NA 0  3 10
## 3 2020-02-02  1 1  2  9
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Say if there were now two dates (e.g. 2020-04-05 and 2020-05-06) in df2 that pertain to df1's 2020-01-01. How could I create an extra row so that there are two rows with "2020-01-01" with the appropriate joined values?

Comment: The first sql statement does that.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. I meant if date in df2 was able to join with the closest df1 date (also within 12 months). For example if df1 had an extra "2020-02-02" it would join with this date instead of "2020-01-01"

Comment: Two different rows in df1 can join with the same row in df2 if they both satisfy the join condition.

Comment: I see, but is it possible for dates in df2 to join with only the closest date in df1? (even if there are multiple dates in df1 that satisfy that join condition?)

Comment: See *Added* section.

Answer (score 0):

a dplyr solution though G. Grothendiecks answer it top notch!!

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    # generate all possible combinations (possibly RAM expensive)
    dplyr::full_join(df2, by = character()) %>%
    # convert specific sample data columns to date
    dplyr::mutate(across(contains("date"), as.Date)) %>%
    # subset the data (you could use other functions here but this is exact enough as we are lookin on months)
    dplyr::filter(date.y > date.x & date.y < (date.x + 365.25)) %>%
    # rename and select columns
    dplyr::select(date = 1, 2, 3, 5, 6)

        date    A B C  D
1 2020-01-01    5 4 2  9
2 2018-01-01 <NA> 0 3 10
```

about you question: it is possible in this dplyr pipe to solve the aditional task you requestes though it is not the best solution.

```
# modified df2 so it does not match any of df1 in your criteria
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2018-01-01"), A = c("5", NA), B = c("4", "0"))
df2 <- data.frame(date = c("2017-02-02"), C = c("2"), D = c("11"))

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    # generate all possible combinations (possibly RAM expensive)
    dplyr::full_join(df2, by = character()) %>%
    # convert specific sample data columns to date
    dplyr::mutate(across(contains("date"), as.Date)) %>%
    # subset the data (you could use other functions here but this is exact enough as we are lookin on months)
    dplyr::filter(date.y > date.x & date.y < (date.x + 365.25)) %>%
    # rename and select columns
    dplyr::select(date = 1, 2, 3, 5, 6) %>%
    # bind the missing data back by selecting from within the pipe
    dplyr::union(df1[!df1$date %in% unique(.$date),] %>% 
                     # we have to simulate the missing columns and correct the date as dplyr::union() need the columns to match by name and type
                     dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(date),
                                   # you have to get the right NA_xxxx_ for you columns (critical!)
                                   C = NA_character_,
                                   D = NA_character_))

            date    A B    C    D
    1 2020-01-01    5 4 <NA> <NA>
    2 2018-01-01 <NA> 0 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this detailed answer! Is there a way to keep every row in df1, essentially doing a left join? Also just wondering if it was possible for dates in df2 to join with only the closest date in df1? (even if there are multiple dates in df1 that satisfy the condition of 'after and within 12 months')

Comment: there is a way but it is not very pretty though you stay within the dplyr pipe (plz see the altered answer)